# Python dictionary comprehension to group together equal keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a code snippit that groups together equal keys from a list of dicts and adds the dict with equal ObjectID to a list under that key.
Code bellow works, but I am trying to convert it to a  Dictionary comprehension

**group togheter subblocks if they have equal ObjectID**

```
output = {}
subblkDBF : list[dict]
for row in subblkDBF:
    if row["OBJECTID"] not in output:
        output[row["OBJECTID"]] = []
    output[row["OBJECTID"]].append(row)
```

Comment: don't, you'll have to do something much more inefficient, stick with this approach

Comment: If rows are sorted by object ID you could use `itertools.groupby`, otherwise you'd have to sort by that key first.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yes you might be correct, am am not able to time any improvments since I am not able to make the list comp.
 I am trying to streamline my software. make it more like a Ferrari then a ferry.

Comment: self.item is different from item, so thre is some confusion

Comment: @EspenEnes. The dict/list comp is necessarily O(n^2) or worse, while your current approach is O(n)

Comment: self.item is different from item, so thre is some confusion

Comment: @rv.kvetch. I don't see how that's an issue here.

Comment: @tobias_k, I will look into itertools.groupby for future use. but I was trying to use dict comp in this example

Comment: @MadPhysicist well, my meaning is that the type annotation is a bit pointless, since the var item is not used, but agree it is minor thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a comprehension is possible, but likely inefficient in this case, since you need to (a) check if a key is in the dictionary at every iteration, and (b) append to, rather than set the value. You can, however, eliminate some of the boilerplate using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
output = defaultdict(list)
for row in subblkDBF:
    output[row['OBJECTID']].append(row)
```

The problem with using a comprehension is that if really want a one-liner, you have to nest a list comprehension that traverses the entire list multiple times (once for each key):

```
{k: [d for d in subblkDBF if d['OBJECTID'] == k] for k in set(d['OBJECTID'] for d in subblkDBF)}
```

Iterating over `subblkDBF` in both the inner and outer loop leads to O(n^2) complexity, which is pointless, especially given how illegible the result is.

As the other answer shows, these problems go away if you're willing to sort the list first, or better yet, if it is already sorted.

Comment: this is the way

Comment: @JulesG.M. I added the comprehension anyway :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist OMG, so easy,    almost perfect   thanks.
Not the list comp.   but the other example

Comment: thanks  @MadPhysicist  for the quick replies.
I did not see any improvements beyond the initial post.
dict comp, made the software 30-50ms slower and the use of defaultdict was same.

but defaultdict was amazing, I cant understand why I have not found it earlier

Comment: @EspenEnes. You'll see a much bigger difference for large datasets. Algorithmic complexity is not very important for tiny datasets.

Answer (score 3):

If rows are sorted by Object ID (or all rows with equal Object ID are at least next to each other, no matter the overall order of those IDs) you could write a neat dict comprehension using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

output = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(subblkDBF, key=itemgetter("OBJECTID"))}
```

However, if this is not the case, you'd have to sort by the same `key` first, making this a lot less neat, and less efficient than above or the loop (O(nlogn) instead of O(n)).

```
key = itemgetter("OBJECTID")
output = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(subblkDBF, key=key), key=key)}
```

Comment: thanks @tobias_k for the quick replies. I did not see any improvements beyond the initial post. dict comp, made the software 30-50ms slower

Answer (score 0):

You can adding an `else` block to safe on time n slightly improve perfomrance a little:

```py
output = {}
subblkDBF : list[dict]
for row in subblkDBF:
    if row["OBJECTID"] not in output:
        output[row["OBJECTID"]] = [row]
    else:
        output[row["OBJECTID"]].append(row)
```

Comment: Have you run a benchmark to verify this?

Comment: @MadPhysicist nope, not yet

Comment: @rv.kvetch, this gave no noticeable effect.  but thanks for the answer